# In R how do you write a sparse matrix to a file?

Tags: r, matrix, statistics, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix A, generated as an output of glmnet function.
When I print the matrix A, it shows all the entries and at the top it reads -

```
    1897 x 100 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
   [[ suppressing 32 column names 's0', 's1', 's2' ... ]]
```

However, when I try to see the dimensions of the matrix it shows NULL:

```
> dim(A)
NULL
```

Thus if I use as.matrix to convert it into a regular matrix and write to a file I get an error:

```
as.matrix(fit$A[,1])
Error in as.matrix(fit$A[, 1]) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.matrix': Error in fit$A[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

How do I fetch the values in this sparse matrix and write to a file?

I encounter this problem when I do multinomial regression (family = "multinomial") in the glmnet function. However this works fine when I am doing binomail regression (family = "binomial").

Also, I have tried with writeMM function. That does not work either:

```
> library('Matrix')
> writeMM(fit$A,file='test.txt')
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function 'writeMM' for signature '"list"'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `writeMM` and `readMM` to Read and write sparse matrix, so no need to coerce it to a matrix.

```
writeMM(fit$A,file='test.txt')
readMM(file='test.txt')
```

**EDIT** within `multinomial`, glmnet returns a list of coefficients. SO you need to loop over this list and write each coefficient. Here an example:

```
library(glmnet)
g4=sample(1:4,100,replace=TRUE)
fit3=glmnet(x,g4,family="multinomial")
lapply(seq_along(fit3$beta),function(x)
       writeMM(fit3$beta[[x]],file=paste0('coef.beta',x,'.txt')))
```

Comment: I get this error -> > writeMM(fit$A,file='test.txt')
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function 'writeMM' for signature '"list"'

Comment: Thanks @agstudy. Awesome!! This works. But pardon my limited knowledge in R. I am not sure what each of these files denote? How to interpret the output? What does the different coefficients mean? My ultimate purpose is to see the different beta coefficients for each of the predictive variables in the model. Its straightforward to get that with 'binomial' regression. With 'multinomial' regression, right now I get 3 files corresponding to three coefficients and each are of different length. How do I interpret these?